# group and calculate different product models percentages

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I have a large data-set and used this code to group different products and different models of every product.

```
val tt2 = dTestSample1.groupBy("Product", "model" )
                      .agg( count("Product") as "countItems" )
                      .withColumn("percentage", (col("countItems") / sum("countItems").over())* 100)
                      .sort("Product")
```

So far, the results are accurate [in this table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfN6Z.jpg).

Can any one help me to improve the code to be able to calculate percentages of every model out of the products?

To clarify the idea [this table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSKgZ.jpg) was done manually and can be taken as an example.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking for a windowing function.

```
val winSpec = Window.partitionBy("product")
df.withColumn("totalPerProduct", sum("countItems").over(winSpec)
```

Then you can calculate the percentages easily after that.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I was looking for!